# WSUS TargetGroup being populated from...somewhere

Tags: group-policy, wsus

I have a WSUS 3.0 SP2 environment, using Server-side trageting, but some clients are getting a registry entry for TargetGroup, as if they were managed using Client-side targeting. Interestingly the TargetGroup name is not even vaguely valid - is a seemingly random string, over 255 char long, and so fails without attempting to connect to anything.  I have never used Client-side targeting.

Have searched the GPO's applying to these targets, and manually deleted the TargetGroup entry to see if the GPO would re-populate it, but it remains blank.  Sometime in the next 30 days or so (when i go to test patches again), the clients stop responding, and the registry entries have changed again.

Note is only some clients, but seems to be the same ones each time.

Any clues would be appreciated,
Justin

Comment: Were these clients deployed from an image?

Comment: Yep. After imaging, we run a batch to delete and re-create the SoftwareDistribution and CatRoot2 folders, and then restart the wsus service and run

 wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow

Comment: I should have asked if you Sysprep the image. If not then the clients will have a duplicate SUS ID, which may be contributing to your problem. You need each client to create a new SUS ID. You can use the linked script to do so. - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-WSUS-Authorization-2e26d1b0

Comment: Thanks Joe, have given that a crack and so-far, so-good - 4 hours later the PC is reporting to WSUS and is notifying of pending updates. Will update again in 18 hours, cheers

Comment: Hmm. No joy, TargetGroup has been repopulated from somewhere and the WSUS host has been reset to the Microsoft host. Doesn't seem to he GPO related, i can deleted the TargetGroup registry setting and gpupate /force the clients, and get the expected, correct result (i.e. no TargetGroup and internal WSUS URL). Then sometime in the next 24 hours it gets reset back to a TargetGroup and the MSFT WSUS URL.

Answer (score 0):

Never did get to the bottom of this. The units that were incurring the issue have since been re-imaged, and I was careful to manually remove them from WSUS before re-creating PC's with the same computer name. Both have since re-joined the WSUS host without incident - Justin.